# How to implement a kill command in my own shell

Tags: c

I'm trying to create my shell in C, but I don't know how to implement the kill function.
I can't use the command kill(), I want to create my own function by insert for exemple " k *process_pid* ".

Here my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <signal.h>
    #define maxarg 20

    void CtrlC(int sig);
    void execute(char *argv[]);
    char getargs(int *argcp, char *argv[], int max);

    int main () {

     signal(SIGINT,CtrlC);
     char *argv[maxarg+1];
     int argc;

     while (1) {
         printf(">");

         if(!getargs(&argc, argv, maxarg) || argc == 0) {
             continue;
         }      

         if(strncmp(argv[0], "exit", 4) == 0) {
             printf("Program completed.\n");
             exit(0);
         }  
         execute(argv); 
     }

 }

 char getargs(int *argcp, char *argv[], int max){

     static char cmd[100];
     char *cmdp;
     int i;

     if(gets(cmd) == NULL)
         exit(0);

     cmdp = cmd;

     for(i=0; i<=max; i++){

         if((argv[i] = strtok(cmdp, " \t")) == NULL)
             break;
         cmdp = NULL;
     }

     if(i > max){
         printf(">Too many arguments!\n");
         return -1;
     }

     *argcp = i;
     return(1);
 }

 void execute(char *argv[]) {
     int i;

     switch (fork()) {

         case -1:
             printf(">Error in the creation of the process.\n");
             return;

         case 0:
             execvp(argv[0], argv);

             printf(">Can't execute.\n");
             perror(">execvp");
             exit(1);

         default:
             if(wait(NULL) == -1)
                 perror(">Wait");
     }
 }

 void CtrlC (int sig) {

    signal(sig, SIG_IGN);
    printf("\n>To exit digit 'exit'.\n>");
    signal(SIGINT,CtrlC);
    fflush(stdout);
 }
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: please format your code, the indentation is wonky.

Comment: Kill command just sends a signal to the process, by default SIGKILL. It's no different from sending SIGINT.

Comment: ok but how I can send the SIGKILL to a determinate process when I type " k pid " ?And how I get the pid and use it with the SIGKILL?

Comment: @Furla94 kill source code is available...

Comment: I know but I can't cpoy and paste it in my program.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what you did with the `exit` command, you just have to:

- test for `!strncmp(argv[0],"k",1)`
- then decode the pid with `sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&pid)`
- then kill it with `kill(pid,SIGTERM)` (or any other signal you want)